# Jquery function not working properly the second time I call it

Tags: jquery, function, html

I'm really new to Jquery. I'm having trouble using the same function multiple times. I'm trying to create a FAQ page. The first FAQ functions properly but the second one doesn't.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#flip").click(function(){
      $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
</script>
```

and here is where I call the functions

```
<body>

<div id="flip">How do I delete FAQ's?</div>
<div id="panel">I don't know</div>

<div id="flip"><h1>Why doesn't this work?</h1></div>
<div id="panel"><p>I still don't know</p></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `ID` MUST be unique

Use class instead associate with an attribute to specify which panel must be displayed like this :

```
<div class="flip" target="panelA">How do I delete FAQ's?</div>
<div class="panel" id="panelA">I don't know</div>

<div class="flip" target="panelB"><h1>Why doesn't this work?</h1></div>
<div class="panel" id="panelB"><p>I still don't know</p></div>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".flip").click(function(){
      $('#' + $(this).attr('target')).slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "starts with" selector like

```
$("[id^=flip]").click(function(){//your code here})
```

bind function to all elements with an id that starts with "flip".